# Bean type not be found

Tags: spring, spring-boot, redis

I'm encountering an issue with my Spring Boot application and need assistance to resolve it. Below is the relevant code and the error message:

**MessageRepository:**

```
package com.test.listener;

import com.test.model.MessageEntity;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface MessageRepository extends CrudRepository<MessageEntity, String> {
}
```

**MessageHandlingService:**

```
package com.test.listener;

import com.test.model.MessageEntity;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class MessageHandlingService {

    @Autowired
    private MessageRepository messageRepository;

    public void handleRetransmissionFailure(String messageId, String message) {
        // Retrieve the message entity by ID or create a new one
        MessageEntity entity = messageRepository.findById(messageId).orElseGet(() -> {
            MessageEntity newEntity = new MessageEntity();
            newEntity.setId(messageId);
            return newEntity;
        });

        // Update message details and retry count
        entity.setMessage(message);
        entity.setAcknowledged(false);
        entity.setRetryCount(entity.getRetryCount() + 1);
        entity.setTimestamp(System.currentTimeMillis());

        // Save the message entity in Redis
        messageRepository.save(entity);

        // Log the transmission failure
        logTransmissionFailure(messageId);

        // You may also have additional logic here, such as notifying administrators or implementing custom retry policies.
    }

    private void logTransmissionFailure(String messageId) {
        System.out.println("Transmission failure ");
    }
}

**MyApplication:**

package com.test.main;

@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.test","com.test.model"})
public class MyApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
       SpringApplication.run(MyApplication.class, args);
      
    }
    
    
}
```

I'm receiving the following error when trying to run the application:

---

APPLICATION FAILED TO START

---

Description:

Field messageRepository in com.varpm.listener.MessageHandlingService required a bean of type 'com.varpm.listener.MessageRepository' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
- @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)

Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.varpm.listener.MessageRepository' in your configuration.

Process finished with exit code 1

Your assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Spring can't find a bean of type `com.varpm.listener.MessageRepository` because the package `com.varpm.listener` isn't declared in the `@ComponentScan` configuration

Comment: Thanks but my MessageRepository is under package com.test.listener. Changed my package but still it is not working